# Other ways of checking whether particular system result in non-locality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, locality

In quantum mechanics, when hamiltonian $H$ is constrained ($H = \sqrt{m^2 - \hbar^2 \nabla^2} $) so that it would produce simple "relativistic" model of quantum mechanics, we can show that it results in non-locality (Reference: [$\nabla$ and non-locality in simple relativistic model of quantum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39415/nabla-and-non-locality-in-simple-relativistic-model-of-quantum-mechanics) )

The question is would Taylor-expanding every constraint equation on some quantity/operator, such as Hamiltonian, show that it will result in non-locality? Or in some case, should we check other expansions/methods?

Comment: anyone........?

Comment: any comment...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the specific case of the Hamiltonian the non-locality arises because the **time evolution** depends on values of the field which are arbitrary far away. In the one dimensional case we have

\begin{equation}
i \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\, \psi ~~~=~~~  \tilde{H}\,\psi ~~=\ \sqrt{~m^2+\mathbf{\tilde{p}}^2_x~}\ \psi\ =\ \nonumber
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{ ~m^2-\partial_x^2~}~~      \psi  ~~=~~ \frac{m}{x}  K_1\left(mx\right) ~*~ \psi ~~~~~~~
\end{equation}

( We used $\hbar=c=1$ ).  In the last term $*$ denotes a convolution, in this case with a [Bessel K function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_:_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1). It is clear that this instantaneous dependency violates the speed of light restriction.

See also my stackexchange answer here: [$\nabla$ and non-locality in simple relativistic model of quantum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39415/nabla-and-non-locality-in-simple-relativistic-model-of-quantum-mechanics)

Now in the general case the value of $\psi(x)$  will depend on $\psi(y)$ at other locations **in the past** an it will depend on other fields such as $A^\mu(y)$ at other locations in the past.

Mathematically these dependencies stem from *"Taylor-expanded series"* of differential operators but as long as you don't violate the speed of light restriction then this is perfectly fine.

Hans