# Wave functions in complex scalar free field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Consider free complex scalar theory. Let's denote $a(p)^{\dagger}$ as the particle creation operator, and $b(p)^{\dagger}$ as the antiparticle creation operator. I know that an arbitrary one particle state is given by
$$|1\rangle=\int{}d^3p\,g(p)a(p)^{\dagger}|0\rangle$$
where $g(p)$ is a sufficiently well behaved function. I wanna know how to compute the wave function of such a state, but I have never been told how to compute $|x\rangle$ in this context.

So, how do I compute the wave function? Would there be any difference in the way to compute $|x\rangle$ had I chosen a one antiparticle state?

Comment: for a particle that is allowed to decay or give place to something else in general its position makes little sense...

Comment: There is not really a good position representation in relativistic QFT, and hence no good notion of "wavefunction", see [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/83365/50583) and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/142454/50583), for instance. If you are asking about the non-relativistic case (as the non-Lorentz invariant integration measure would imply), then I don't see what your problem would be, just Fourier transform $g(p)$.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that $p$ denotes a momentum coordinate, the function $g(p)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is your one particle wavefunction in the momentum representation.

More precisely, the vector $\lvert 1\rangle=\Bigl(\lvert 1\rangle_0,\lvert 1\rangle_1(p_1),\dotsc,\lvert 1\rangle_n(p_1,p_2,\dotsc,p_n),\dotsc\Bigl)$ that you has written (where $\lvert 1\rangle_n(p_1,\dotsc,p_n)$ is the $n$-particle component in momentum representation) has the form
$$\lvert 1_g\rangle=\Bigl(0,g(p),0,\dotsc,0,\dotsc\Bigl)\; ;$$
i.e. it is an infinite vector with zero components, apart from the second that represents a single particle with wavefunction $g(p)$.

As usual, you can recover the wavefunction in position representation by Fourier transform in $L^2$, i.e.
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} e^{ip\cdot x}g(p)d^3p\; .$$