# Is the phase velocity of plane wave solutions of the Klein-Gordon equation larger than $c$?

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light, klein-gordon-equation, phase-velocity

The phase velocity is given by
$$ v= \frac{\omega}{k} \, .$$
Using the usual dispersion relation
$$ E^2 = p^2c^2+ m^2c^4 \leftrightarrow \omega^2 \hbar^2= k^2\hbar^2 c^2 + m^2c^4$$
yields
$$ v= \frac{\sqrt{k^2c^2 + \frac{m^2c^4 }{\hbar^2} }}{k} \, .$$
If we now assume that $k^2\gg \frac{ m^2c^2}{\hbar^2} $, we can Taylor expand the square root
\begin{align} v&= \frac{\sqrt{k^2c^2 + \frac{m^2c^4 }{\hbar^2} }}{k} \\
&=\frac{kc \sqrt{ + \frac{m^2c^2 }{\hbar^2 k^2} }}{k} \\
& \approx c(1+\frac{m^2c^2 }{2\hbar^2 k^2}) \, .
\end{align}
This seems to suggest that $v> c$. Moreover, the velocity gets smaller the larger the wave vector/momentum $k$ is. Is this correct or (more likely) did I do some stupid mistake in the calculation above?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6912/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/503967/2451 and links therein.

Comment: In case [anomalous dispersion](https://www.nature.com/articles/35018657) one can watch phase velocity $ > c $, but this has nothing to do with information or energy transfer, so this fact is not breaking causality, albeit is very interesting